# How does Entity Framework handle auto-implemented properties in .NET (VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am new to EF and have a VB.NET project which has auto-implemented properties.  How does EF handle auto-implemented properties, in that, will I have/run into issues with migrating an existing solution/DB to EF where auto-implemented properties is present?

(All the existing DB/Solution migrations I've come across so far explicitly state the get & set)

Example:

```
 Public Property Name As String
 Public Property Owner As String = "DefaultName"
 Public Property Items As New List(Of String) From {"M", "T", "W"}
 Public Property ID As New Guid()
```

Versus:

```
Private _Prop2 As String = "Empty"
Property Prop2 As String
Get
    Return _Prop2
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
    _Prop2 = value
End Set
End Property
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Better add a sample of what you mean. Also tag for VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you won't have any issues with auto-implemented properties. It generates those auto props when using DB First.

I suggest looking into DB First, Code First or Model first. It's better to have a more solid link between your DB and code rather than a weak link which requires you to make code/db changes whenever either or is updated

Comment: Thanks so much.  Will I have any issues with auto-implemented for Code First as there seems to be a higher number of pro Code First recommendations through my searches?  Thanks again

Comment: @McCarson Auto-implemented properties are totally OK (you will find myriad of examples for EF where they are used). In general, EF needs to set and get values from your properties. Limiting accessibility of your property makes it unusable for EF.